# Always load zero values after storing other values in memory, in ARM Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm making two subroutines in ARM Assembly. One is supposed to store a byte value at the first available position of a vector. This one, called "appendbyte" in my code, seems to work fine. The other is supposed to print the values stored in this vector, but it prints 0 for all elements in it, which isn't right.

The vector structure has the number of elements stored in the first address of the vector, and it must have up to 255 values stored in it.

Here is the full code:

```
    .text
    .global main    
    .equ    num, 255    @ Max number of elements

main:
    push    {lr}

    mov r8, #7
    bl appendbyte
    mov r8, #5
    bl appendbyte
    mov r8, #8
    bl appendbyte
    bl printvector

    pop {pc}

printvector:
    push {lr}

    ldr r4, =vet @ stores the address of the start of the vector in r4
    ldr r5, [r4], #1 @ stores the number of elements in r5

loop:
    cmp r5, #0 @if there isn't elements to print
    beq fimimprime @quit subroutine
    ldr r0, =node   @r0 receives the print format
    ldr r1, [r4], #1 @stores in r1 the value of the element pointed by r4. Increments r4 after that.
    sub r5, r5, #1 @decrements r5 (number of elements left to print)
    bl printf @call printf
    b loop @continue on the loop

endprint:
    pop {pc}

appendbyte:
    push {lr}

    ldr r4, =vet    @stores in r4 the beggining address of the vector
    ldr r5, [r4], #1    @stores in r5 the number of elements and makes r4 point to the next address
    add r6, r4, r5  @stores in r6 the address of the first available position
    str r8, [r6]    @put the value at the first available position
    ldr r4, =vet    @stores in r4 the beggining address of the vector
    add r5, r5, #1  @ increment the number of elements in the vector
    str r5, [r4]    @ stores it in the vector

    pop {pc}

.data           @ Read/write data follows
.align          @ Make sure data is aligned on 32-bit boundaries
vet:    .byte 0
    .skip   num     @ Reserve num bytes

.align
node:   .asciz "[%d]\n"

.end
```

I hope I was clear with the problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `ldrb` and `strb` in all places where you're accessing the vector length, since the length element is a single byte?

Comment: @Michael If I do that I get a seg fault error in the line 3 of the "appendbyte" subroutine (ldrb r5, [r4], #1)

Comment: @Michael It seems to work now, but the only place I can't use ldrb is when I load the beggining of the vector (like in ldr r4, =vet). In this case I use 'ldr'. Why is that?

Comment: Because there you're not accessing the vector; you're loading its address (which is one word).

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Thanks a lot!